# Calculating number of complete boxes and loose items for Scout Popcorn Sale

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm working on a table to calculate popcorn orders for my Boy Scout Troop annual sale. I want to calculate how many cases and loose item count of a specific item I should be receiving.

For example, let's say the troop sold 205 Caramel Popcorn bags and each Caramel Popcorn box contains 12 bags. I want to display how many boxes I should be getting in one cell plus how many loose bags I should be getting if the remainder does not complete a whole box, and so on with each popcorn flavor.

I tried a cell with a formula dividing 205/12 but it gives me a number with decimal portion.  I know how hide the decimal point but I would like to convert the decimal portion of that number to a loose item count in another cell.

In addition, I need to count how many cases and loose items of all flavors I need to have but, even though I hid the decimal point, summing up all the cases gives me an incorrect number since it takes into account the decimal portion although I've hidden it.

How can i do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you give us an example how the data is entered into the spreadsheet? For example, column A contains flavor, column B contains bag count, column C contains case totals, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: This is just an example since we don't know how your sheet is laid out.**

To calculate the remainder of a division, the `MOD` function can be used.

```
=MOD(number, divisor)
```

In your case, you would want to use it like this;

```
=MOD(bags sold, case quantity)
```

In the example below, column C calculates the whole cases and column D runs the `MOD` function on the value in `B2` to calculate the loose bags. In this example you will end up with 17 cases and 1 loose bag.

[image]

You can then drag the calculation to other rows and recalculate the sheet to get your totals.

[image]